# PHP filter_input validate and sanitize

Tags: php, filter-input

I'm coding a contact form and I want to validate and sanitize user input using filter_input
The problem is that because I use it for every POST variable shall I do a validate then sanitize or what? my suggestion is as follows:

```
if (!filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
exit ();
} else {
$email  = $_POST['email'];
}
```

is this OK or I must re-sanitize the $_POST['email']

Thanks

Comment: What you're trying to achieve isn't really clear. Why are you sanitizing? For SQL injection?

Comment: maybe yes maybe no as I will choose then to store the messages in db or send them by email

Comment: (2 years later) You can use [filter_has_var()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-has-var.php) to check if the post is set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ( !$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    exit();
}

echo $email
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` before using `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` would be better. Also, I would suggest making a regular expression that forced email addresses to conform to what you want to accept for an email address. Both `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` and `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` are very liberal in the characters they will accept (the RFC allows more kinds of characters than you might want to allow, and in places you might not care to see them in).